# You can talk to her?

Tags: grammar

Which is correct?

***You can talk to her.***

(a) you are permitted to talk to her.
(b) you must talk to her
(c) you might talk to her.

Comment: We need some context.  Any of these could be correct, depending on the situation.

Comment: Also, you need not be nervous about talking to her. Context is everything.

Answer (score 2):

**can** in colloquial contexts often is used to mean "is|are permitted". So

> You can talk to her.

could mean

> You are permitted to talk to her.

It could also refer to some *capability*, either of yours or of hers:

> Here's my new robot. You can talk to her.

That is, "she has the ability to carry on a conversation".

> Here's my new robot, via this microphone you can talk to her.

That is, you have the power to issue commands to the robot via this microphone.

So, without further context, there's no way to know what your sentence might mean.